# String truncate on length, but no chopping up of words allowed

Tags: mysql, sql, substring

I want to limit a string field length in MYSQL on a certain length, but I don't want any chopping up of words to occur.

When I do:

```
SELECT SUBSTRING('Business Analist met focus op wet- en regelgeving', 1, 28)
```

I get this as output:

```
Business Analist met focus o
```

But I would like

```
Business Analist met focus
```

How can I enforce a limit of 28 chars, but prevent chopping up words? Off course it's easy in [insert programming language of choice here] ;-), but I want to know if it's possible in MYSQL in a simple statement.

Comment: You're looking for "word wrap" in MySQL. Sort of.

Comment: You need logic here. In other words, you need an if statement. If MySQL supports if, then use that, otherwise, no way

Comment: i think that's quite expensive operation for mysql. just chop the word and get rid of it later in whatever programming language you're using.

Comment: @keymone  Not really, see point 5 (5. Favoring PHP over SQL) at http://www.sitepoint.com/mysql-mistakes-php-developers/

Comment: @bicycle there is a difference between implementing AVG in your PHP and doing substring. chances are that if you're doing substring you will need to do other more complex operations in php anyway.

Comment: @keymone Good points. The reason why I needed this at the time in MYSQL is that the output then could be directly fed into a full text search engine. This would shorten the index time considerably.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Let `@str` be your string and `@len` the initial position to cut at. Then the necessary steps could be:

1. Take the leftmost `@len` characters of `@str`.
2. Reverse the substring.
3. Find the position of the first space in the reversed substring.
4. Subtract `1` from the position. But if no space was found, let the position remain `0`.
5. Subtract the found position from `@len` and call it `cutpos`.
6. Take the first (leftmost) `cutpos` characters of `@str` as `str1`, take all the other characters (starting from `cutpos+1`) as `str2`.

```
SELECT
  LEFT(str, cutpos) AS str1,
  SUBSTRING(str, cutpos + 1) AS str2
FROM (
  SELECT
    @str AS str,
    @len - IFNULL(NULLIF(LOCATE(' ', REVERSE(LEFT(@str, @len))), 0) - 1, 0) AS cutpos
) s
```

Answer (score 13):

What about splitting on spaces :

```
SELECT SUBSTRING_INDEX('Business Analist met focus op wet- en regelgeving',' ',4)
```

will return

```
Business Analist met focus
```

Answer (score 3):

Very interesting problem.  Here's how I did it:

```
//gets initial string - use 29 instead of 28 to see if the 29th  character is a space
SELECT SUBSTRING('Business Analist met focus op wet- en regelgeving', 1, 29) 

//inverts the string, so we can get the first 
SELECT REVERSE( SUBSTRING('Business Analist met focus op wet- en regelgeving', 1, 29))

// find the charindex of the first space (last space in the string not reversed)
SELECT CHARINDEX(' ', REVERSE( SUBSTRING('Business Analist met focus op wet- en regelgeving', 1, 29)))

// get the substring from the first (last) space
SELECT  SUBSTRING(REVERSE( SUBSTRING('Business Analist met focus op wet- en regelgeving', 1, 29)), CHARINDEX(' ', REVERSE( SUBSTRING('Business Analist met focus op wet- en regelgeving', 1, 29))), 29)

// reverse the string again to unfold it.
SELECT REVERSE(SUBSTRING(REVERSE( SUBSTRING('Business Analist met focus op wet- en regelgeving', 1, 29)), CHARINDEX(' ', REVERSE( SUBSTRING('Business Analist met focus op wet- en regelgeving', 1, 29))), 29))


// to try different lengths...
DECLARE  @size  int
select @size = 24
SELECT REVERSE(SUBSTRING(REVERSE( SUBSTRING('Business Analist met focus op wet- en regelgeving', 1, @size)), 
CHARINDEX(' ', REVERSE( SUBSTRING('Business Analist met focus op wet- en regelgeving', 1, @size))), @size))
```

Comment: charindex is not a valid mysql function. It should be LOCATE instead. This one should be the best answer btw.

Comment: This worked for me, but I had to change CHARINDEX to LOCATE

Answer (score 0):

In SQL it would be...

```
select Substring('Business Analist met focus op wet- en regelgeving', 0 , 28 + 2 - CharIndex(' ',  REVERSE(SUBSTRING('Business Analist met focus op wet- en regelgeving', 0, 28 + 1 )),0))
```

I dont know if all these functions are available in MYSQL

EDIT: I think for MYSQL substitute "Locate" for "CharIndex"

Answer (score 0):

Build on Narnian's answer, here's one that works with two fields (a.product,a.descr) and where "..." is added when the string is truncated.  a.descr can be empty as well.

```
  IF (
CHARACTER_LENGTH(
  IF(
    a.descr = '',
    a.product,
    CONCAT_WS(' - ',a.product,a.descr)
  )
)>35,
IF(
  a.descr = '',
  CONCAT(
    REVERSE(SUBSTRING(REVERSE( SUBSTRING(a.product, 1, 35)), locate(' ', REVERSE( SUBSTRING(a.product, 1, 35))), 35)),
    '...'
  ),
  CONCAT(
    REVERSE(SUBSTRING(REVERSE( SUBSTRING(CONCAT_WS(' - ',a.product,a.descr), 1, 35)), locate(' ', REVERSE( SUBSTRING(CONCAT_WS(' - ',a.product,a.descr), 1, 35))), 35)),
    '...'
  )
),
CONCAT_WS(' - ',a.product,a.descr)
)
```

I needed something like this so that's why i added it. Might help someone else.

Comment: Was that by any chance you who downvoted my answer some 3 hours ago? If so, I would really appreciate if you elaborated on your reasons. By the way, when you are checking the length at the beginning, you are verifying whether `descr` is empty and, depending on that, checking the length of either `product` alone or the two columns delimited with `-`. But later on, when you are actually finding the position to cut, you are no longer checking if `descr` is empty or not. That might not result in the most precise cut sometimes, I think.

Comment: true indeed, good point. I just adjusted it. Yeah i downvoted you because the other answer is easier to implement without too much customisation. It should be adjusted though since charindex is not a valid mysql method while the quesion is about mysql. should be locate instead.

Comment: But it doesn't cover the case when a space is not found within the specified length. Neither does yours, as a matter of fact. I realise that omitting that case might have made that solution look easier, though. Either way, thanks for explaining your downvote!

Answer (score 0):

@Andriy M. I liked very much your answer :)
Anyway I find on my db it works better if you change lines 2 and 3 like this:

```
SELECT
  IF(LENGTH(str)<=@len,str,LEFT(str, cutpos)) AS str1,
  IF(LENGTH(str)<=@len,'',SUBSTRING(str, cutpos + 1)) AS str2
FROM (
  SELECT
    @str AS str,
    @len - IFNULL(NULLIF(LOCATE(' ', REVERSE(LEFT(@str, @len))), 0) - 1, 0) AS cutpos
  FROM @table
) s
```

Don't know if it's my fault or what, but the other way it sometimes truncated strings on the first letter when their length was <@len, i.e. "First s" - "tring" instead of "First" "string" when @len=13

I post you a working example:

```
CREATE TABLE `test` (
  `sometext` varchar(65)
);

INSERT INTO `test` (`sometext`) VALUES
('Firs strin'),
('Alll right'),
('third string'),
('fourth string'),
('a longer example string'),
('Supercalifragilisticexpialidocious');

SELECT
  IF(LENGTH(str)<=12,str,LEFT(str, cutpos)) AS str1,
  IF(LENGTH(str)<=12,'',SUBSTRING(str, cutpos + 1)) AS str2
FROM (
  SELECT
    sometext AS str,
    12 - IFNULL(NULLIF(LOCATE(' ', REVERSE(LEFT(sometext, 12))), 0) - 1, 0) AS cutpos
  FROM test
) s
```

And here is a **not-working** example using your original code:

```
SELECT
  LEFT(str, cutpos) AS str1,
  SUBSTRING(str, cutpos + 1) AS str2
FROM (
  SELECT
    sometext AS str,
    12 - IFNULL(NULLIF(LOCATE(' ', REVERSE(LEFT(sometext,12))), 0) - 1, 0) AS cutpos
  FROM test
) s
```

I'm not sure if it's a utf8 issue, or I just misinterpreted your code, or what else...

Answer (score 0):

Simple function:

```
DROP FUNCTION IF EXISTS fn_maxlen;
delimiter //
CREATE FUNCTION fn_maxlen(s TEXT, maxlen INT) RETURNS VARCHAR(255)
BEGIN

 RETURN LEFT(s, maxlen - LOCATE(' ', REVERSE(LEFT(s, maxlen))));

END//
delimiter ;
```

Use:

```
SELECT fn_maxlen('Business Analist met focus op wet- en regelgeving', 28);
```

Answer (score -3):

Seems like people don't read the mysql manual:

Original: `SELECT SUBSTRING('Business Analist met focus op wet- en regelgeving', 1, 28)` gives broken words.

Modified: `SELECT SUBSTRING_INDEX('Business Analist met focus op wet- en regelgeving', ' ' , 4)` gives unbroken words

`SUBSTRING_INDEX(string, delimiter, number)` will truncate a string by the number of times delimiter is found.
Make your delimiter a space and you will get whole words only. so:

`SUBSTRING_INDEX( LEFT('Business Analist met focus op wet- en regelgeving',28), ' ' , 4)` should do it.

Comment: seems like some poeple don't assume generic inputs... the answer should work for an arbitrary number of words, not just 4! the SUBSTRING_INDEX function is interesting anyway.