# Cut all strings in column to a specified number of characters no chopping words

Tags: mysql, string, cut

I need to find a way to reduce all the entries of a specified column to a specific number of characters, lets say 100, but without chopping words, is this possible in mysql 5.0? I am no programmer, can anybody please help me with this? EDITED: I need to update all rows also, not just select.

Comment: Might help: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6650605/string-truncate-on-length-but-no-chopping-up-of-words-allowed

Comment: thanks, i had seen that thread, but really i am no programmer and i could not understand it... i need to find a query that rund for a speficic column only, i am sorry but I couldnt manage to solve my prob with that thread..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'd probably try something like this:

```sql
SELECT left(line, 100 - locate(' ' ,reverse(left(line, 100))))
FROM lines;
```

Where lines is the table, line is the specific column, and 100 is the length of the line you want.

**EDIT:**

If you want to update them in place (which we do not recommend), then you'd use a simple update statement:

```
UPDATE lines
SET line = left(line, 100 - locate(' ' ,reverse(left(line, 100))));
```

Comment: thanks, i tried it and it worked but this query does not update the lines, i need the lines to be updated in mysql, i tried to use UPDATE instead of select in your code but no luck, how can i update all rows?

Comment: Worth mentioning that it might be a bad idea to update them in place. You'll lose data, which you won't be able to get back.

Comment: yes, thanks a lot, i made a backup and updated... it worked.. thank you so much

Answer (score 2):

Let me describe what you need to do:

1. Consider only the first 101 characters in the string
2. Find the last space in this string.  This is the first space in the reverse of the string.
3. Take the string that is 101- that position.

here is the code in MySQL:

```
select left(val, 100+1 - instr(reverse(left(val, 100+1)), ' '))
```

Comment: thank you very much, and the above code will work for all rows inside a specific column? I just have to run that query in sql without specifying the column name? can you PLEASE tell me the complete query to paste in mysql 5.0? thanks a lot