# How to truncate characters in Mysql without chopping words?

Tags: mysql, substring

The following code works fine:

```
select e.id, e.textOne,
CASE 
WHEN CHAR_LENGTH(e.textTwo) > 30 THEN CONCAT(SUBSTRING(e.textTwo, 1, 30), '...')
ELSE e.textTwo
END AS textTwo
```

How to truncate the string, without breaking the words? I'm not able to get a solution (I've tried: [String truncate on length, but no chopping up of words allowed](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6650605/string-truncate-on-length-but-no-chopping-up-of-words-allowed)).
Any help?
Thank you!

Comment: this may help you http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6650605/string-truncate-on-length-but-no-chopping-up-of-words-allowed?rq=1

Comment: where I have to put it? I have more than one string. I've tried it before..