# Database character limit on the end of word?

Tags: sql, database, limit

Ok, i know I can limit the size of characters of table field while fetching, but most of times that SPLIT comes in the middle of the word:

```
SELECT id, title, LEFT(contents, 300) AS contents FROM posts
```

Now, is it possible to make that SPLIT to come after the word (at space)?

Thank you

Comment: Look at this answer:
 http://stackoverflow.com/a/6653724/1948292

Answer (score 0):

If you are using SQL Server, you can do something like:

```
SELECT id, title,
       LEFT(contents,
            (case when charindex(contents, ' ', 300) > 0
                  then charindex(contents, ' ', 300)
                  else 300
             end)
           ) AS contents
FROM posts;
```

In MySQL:

```
SELECT id, title,
       LEFT(contents,
            (case when locate(' ', contents, 300) > 0
                  then locate(' ', contents, 300)
                  else 300
             end)
           ) AS contents
FROM posts;
```

Other databases have similar functions.

Answer (score 0):

If its Sql Server, you can try this:

```
SELECT id, title,
CASE 
WHEN CHARINDEX(' ', title,300) = 301 THEN LEFT(title, 300)
WHEN CHARINDEX(' ', title,300) > 301 then LEFT(title, CHARINDEX(' ', title, 300) - 1)
END AS Contents
FROM posts
```